# Is iron(iii) hydroxide equivalent to hydrated iron(iii) oxide?

Tags: inorganic-chemistry, bond, crystal-structure

Are the chemicals $\ce{Fe(OH)3}$ and $\ce{Fe2O3⋅3H2O}$ equivalent?  They are both network solids and have the same empirical formula but I know that doesn't always mean they are structurally the same.

Comment: I'd rather not use long words. These two are the same.

Comment: Note that iron(III) hydroxide/hydrated oxide, or more generally all/most such substances of  transient metals, do not have well defined structure nor composition.

Comment: Our lab did over a thousand XRD patterns of corrosion deposits and these compound patterns often showed up , Technicians spent hours with the Fink Index trying to separate them  . From a practical corrosion prevention perspective , it makes no difference.

Answer (score 3):

Fe(OH)<sub>3</sub> is [iron(III) hydroxide](https://pubchem.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/compound/73964), which is a form of [iron hydroxide](https://pubchem.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/compound/Iron-hydroxide-_Fe_OH_3) and is different from anhydrous [iron(III) oxide](https://pubchem.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/compound/518696) (which is Fe<sub>2</sub>O<sub>3</sub>) and [hydrated iron(III) oxide](https://pubchem.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/compound/Iron-oxide-_Fe2O3_-hydrate) (which is Fe<sub>2</sub>O<sub>3</sub>·nH<sub>2</sub>O, where n, in this case is 3). See the list of [iron oxides](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iron_oxide#Oxides) and [iron hydroxides](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iron_oxide#Hydroxides).
Also see [this Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iron(III)_oxide#Hydrated_iron(III)_oxides) which says,

> Several hydrates of Iron(III) oxide exists. When alkali is added to solutions of soluble Fe(III) salts, a red-brown gelatinous precipitate forms. **This is *not* Fe(OH)<sub>3</sub>, but Fe<sub>2</sub>O<sub>3</sub>·H<sub>2</sub>O** (also written as Fe(O)OH). Several forms of the hydrated oxide of Fe(III) exist as well.